# how to fil result fetchall into columns?

Tags: odoo

I used command fetchall()

```
cr.execute('select a.name, a.state, a.amount_total, a.date_confirm, b.product_uom_qty from sale_order a, sale_order_line b where a.id = b.order_id')
temp = cr.fetchall()
```

so it take all SO in table SO, and I want fill all result into here :

```
class sales_items_line(osv.osv_memory):
_name = "sales.items.line"
_description = "Sales Items Line"
_columns = {
    'name': fields.char('Name', size=64),
    'qty': fields.char('Quantity', size=64),
    'date': fields.date('Date', required=True),
    'amount': fields.float('Amount', digits_compute=dp.get_precision('Account')),
    'draft_assigned': fields.boolean('Select'),
    'sale_items_id': fields.many2one('add.sales.items', 'Deposit Items ID'),
}
```

but how ? please help me..., the cr.execute is different class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to override the default_get() method and fill your columns.

Here is the code:

```
def default_get(self, cr, uid, fields, context=None):
    fields = super(sales_items_line, self).default_get(cr, uid, fields, context=context)
    cr.execute('select a.name as "name", a.state as "state", a.amount_total as "total", a.date_confirm as "date", b.product_uom_qty as "qty" from sale_order a, sale_order_line b where a.id = b.order_id')
    data = cr.dictfetchall()
    for rec in data:
        fields['name'] = rec.get('name', '')
        fields['qty'] = rec.get('qty', 0.00)
        fields['amount'] = rec.get('total', 0.00)
    return data
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Thank you.

Comment: sorry, but I got error like this **fields = super(sales_items_line, self).default_get(cr, uid, fields, context=context)
TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type**

Comment: where have you define default_get() method?
It must be define in your "sales_items_line" class.

Comment: please tell me what is meant by 'digits_compute=dp.get_precision('Account'))'  ?